# How to default value for java.lang.long in ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a java.lang.long parameter and would like to set a default value of 0 for that. But I get this error: "cannot convert int to long"
How can I do that? 
Besides, is there any way to set the default value of java.lang.long to NULL?

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the "cannot convert int to long" issue: most likely you have to add `L` to your default parameter, e.g. 0L instead of just 0.

Talking about null - it's not quite clear what's your problem and desired result.

It would me much easier to understand your question if you had provided jrxml showing described problem.

Comment: I mean is that possible to set NULL for java.lang.long parameter instead of 0L?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default value of a Parameter of type Long as :

```
<parameter name="parameterName" class="java.lang.Long">
   <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Long(0)]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

If you don't pass any default value, it will act like a NULL but then if you are planning to use this parameter in query, it will eventually fail in case it is kept empty.